# Construction of a function that is continuous but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I wanted to construct a function that is continuous but not differentiable at some point.
(Other than |x| and Weierstrass function).
Can you guys please let me know if I've constructed a correct example or there is some mistake:
My function is 
$f(x)=\begin{cases}x& \mbox{if} \ x≤0 \\\\
x²& \mbox{if} \ x≥0
\end{cases}$

Here, by definition of differentiability 
$f'(0)$=$\lim\limits_{x\to0}$ $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ , if the limit exists

But here, 
$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}$ $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$

= $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}$ $\frac{x²-0}{x-0}$

=$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}$ $\frac{x²}{x}$

=$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x$

=0

And

$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}$ $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$

= $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}$ $\frac{x-0}{x-0}$

=$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}$ $\frac{x}{x}$

=$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}1$

=1

Hence, $f'(0)$ doesn't exists.

Please tell me whether I'm right or wrong about this!

Comment: You have done it correctly.